# using the DBSet local for multiple queries

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to run queries using the local DBSet but am having issues with the two solution I have come up with.

Solution 1: This will run the query and bind the results of my query to my results control and the data can be edited and saved to the database. However, if I try to run another query on the same table (if I switch tables everything is fine) the results items do not update (it will add any new results but any of the old results that should no longer be there stay there)

```
            //This part gets a DBSet from the context with the passed in table
            Type t = context.GetType();
            dynamic myDBSet= t.InvokeMember(table,
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, context, new object[0]);

            //This is the query I want to run. I am then loading it into the localDBSet
            ((IQueryable)myDBSet).AsQueryable().Where(condition).Load();
            results.ItemsSource = myDBSet.Local;
```

Solution 2: This will run the query and bind the data correctly. Also the data will update for all new queries but the data in the datagrid is no longer editable

```
            //This part gets a DBSet from the context with the passed in table
            Type t = context.GetType();
            dynamic myDBSet= t.InvokeMember(table,
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, context, new object[0]);

            //This is the query I want to run. I am then loading it into the localDBSet
            ((IQueryable)myDBSet).AsQueryable().Where(condition).Load();
            DbSet copiedDBSet= myDBSet;
            results.ItemsSource = copiedDBSet.Local.AsQueryable().Where(condition);
```

Does anyone have a solution that will allow me to run multiple queries and still edit the data?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a solution that will allow me to run multiple queries
>   and still edit the data?

Use a context per query.

That way you can use solution 1 and directly bind to the local observable collection. If you don't want the previous query results then no reason to keep the context. Any reason you are dynamically invoking the context dbset methods and not using the generic `context.Set<T>()`?